# How to invoke a command/operation when the e4 UI is up and running?

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

In my e4 application I want to invoke some operation automatically at that time when the UI is up and running.

I read about introducing a LifeCycleManager - which seemed to be a fit.

- See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html

But apparently I cannot use any of the life cycle annotations listed there.

How can I invoke some operation in e4 that moment the UI has finished coming up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE` event to run code when the application startup is complete.

Adding a method to your life cycle class subscribing to this event is one way of doing that - something like:

```java
@Optional
@Inject
public void appStartupComplete(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE) final Event event)
{
   ....
}
```

Note that `Event` is `org.osgi.service.event.Event`